# How require file 2 times with and without transpilled code by babel

Tags: webpack, require

I'm need require file 2 times.

In first case i need result as **source code**, like this:

```
const code = require('./example')
// result: const a = () => { return 'a' }
```

In second case like **code transpilled with babel**:

```
const code = require('./example')
// result: const a = function() { return 'a' }
```

How i can do this into single build?

I try raw-loader, but file stay transpilled with babel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm need use "!" before raw loader. It prevent all loaders.

```
const code = require('!raw-loader!./example')
```